# new function using require doesn't return value instead returns "add {}"

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
//add.js    
    module.exports = function add(a,b) {
    return a+b
    }
//request.js
    var request = require("add.js")
    var request1 = new request('5','5')
    console.log(request1)
```

this method returns "add {}" instead of 10

Comment: Don't use `new` when the function you want to call is not a constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need to use `new`. Remove that and it works:

```
var request = require("add.js");
var request1 = request('5','5');
console.log(request1);
```

We use `new` when we are exporting a `class`. At that time we use `new` to create a instance of a class.

```
//animal.js
class Animal {

}

module.exports = Animal;

//index.js
var animal = require('animal.js');
//creates a instance of animal
var animalObj = new animal();
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the [**new**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) keyword.

> The new operator creates an instance of a user-defined object type or
>   of one of the built-in object types that has a constructor function.

To achieve the required module import, in order to use this method, you can do the following:

```
// add.js
module.exports = function add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

// request.js
var add = require("./add.js");

add(5, 5) // 10;
```

**Important** In your example you're passing two `strings`, so the result would yield the following as the `+` operator will concatenate the values.

```
add('5','5') // "55"
```